# If I'm programming servlets in Tomcat and some JSON/REST code, do I need the EE SDK or judt JDK?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

Can I program for Tomcat, servlets, etc in IntelliJ with only the JDK SE installed, or do I need to install the EE SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EE doesn't have a separate JDK or JRE. EE is a specification that is implemented by some servlet containers. The EE servlet containers run on Java SE JVM & JRE. I would suggest reading up on the difference between the [Web profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition#Web_profile) and the full EE profile. Many REST services won't need the full EE profile. The Web profile applications will be compiled into a .war artifact, and EE profile applications will be compiled into a .ear artifact.

Tomcat is an implementation of the Web profile, not the full EE profile. If you decide you need EE profile features, check out [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html) or another EE profile container.

Oracle offers a [Java EE SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html), but all it is is an EE servlet container (Glassfish), and some EE examples. It may be a good download if you're interested in using EE features. But if you're only writing servlets for Tomcat you really don't need it.

Comment: Thank you, that's very clear and easy to understand!